# why we cant't import agular4 as librairy like angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

why angularJS came as script to import in html page

but in the new version Angular4, we must use web server to lunch application?

is because angularJS is not a framwork and angular4 it is?

thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is because angular projects are compiled via webpack. While angular js can be interpreted like vanila js.

Comment: I think this question is valid (after some grammatical edits), no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered your question yourself.

**AngularJS** is a library that can be interpreted

**Angular v2 and up** is a Framework and is compiled by webpack.